# I need to create a carousel slider using the data fetch from firebase. i have tried a lots of methods but didn't work

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

This is the firebase database structure that I am using:

[image: ----- database image ----]

```
import 'package:awesome_dropdown/awesome_dropdown.dart';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_controller.dart';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hexated/Refactored/widgets/headings.dart';
import 'package:smooth_page_indicator/smooth_page_indicator.dart';

import '../Refactored/sections/bottomNavigation.dart';
import '../Refactored/sections/todaysMealContainer.dart';
import '../Refactored/widgets/mealDayList.dart';

class messDiary extends StatefulWidget {
  messDiary({Key? key}) : super(key: key) {}

  // late String whatIsToday = DateFormat('EEEE').format(DateTime.now());

  @override
  State<messDiary> createState() => _messDiaryState();
}

class _messDiaryState extends State<messDiary> {
  int activeIndex = 0;
  final carouselController = CarouselController();
  String valueChoose = 'Select a day';
  var itemName;

  final CollectionReference _collectData =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('messdiary');
  late Stream<QuerySnapshot> _streamCollect;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _streamCollect = _collectData.snapshots();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
   
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF000000),
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF000000),
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: const bottomNavigation(),
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          Column(
            children: [
              headings(headingText: "Today's meals"),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 15,
              ),
              StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                  stream: _streamCollect,
                  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                      return const Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      );
                    }
                    List<DocumentSnapshot> snaps = snapshot.data!.docs;
                    return CarouselSlider(
                      options: CarouselOptions(
                        height: height * 0.38,
                        aspectRatio: 2.0,
                        autoPlayCurve: Curves.easeInOutQuart,
                        pauseAutoPlayOnTouch: true,
                        enlargeCenterPage: true,
                        enableInfiniteScroll: false,
                        initialPage: 2,
                        autoPlay: true,
                        onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
                          setState(() {
                            activeIndex = index;
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                      items: snaps.map((e) {
                        return Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
                          return todaysMeal(
                              itemName: e['title'],
                              itemImage: e['image'],
                              time: e['time'],
                              dayTime: e['daytime']);
                        });
                      }).toList(),
                    );
                  }),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 15,
              ),
              AnimatedSmoothIndicator(
                onDotClicked: animateToSlide,
                effect: const ExpandingDotsEffect(
                    dotWidth: 14,
                    dotHeight: 14,
                    activeDotColor: Color(0xFF6A7086),
                    dotColor: Color(0xFF2B2E3F)),
                activeIndex: activeIndex,
                count: 4,
              ),
       
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

**When i try to run the code this error message appears**

> ======== Exception caught by widgets library ======================================================= The following StateError was thrown building Builder(dirty):
>
> Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform

**If it is not the way to access the data then how??**

i have tried to the end and tired please help me to fix this issue!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field names are 'sunday', 'monday', and so on. Each of these fields has an array of [todaysMeal] jsons, in a manner of speaking.

What you are trying to access are the fields inside each array element.

So what's happening is: you are looking for json keys 'title', 'image', 'daytime', and 'time', but the document snapshot has these keys: 'sunday', 'monday', etc.

I don't think I worded this answer very well, but I hope this was enough to clear up your confusion.

---

I am replying to your comments here. Here are the code changes that you can try.

```
// First of all change the don't use the CollectionReference for 'messdiary'.
// final CollectionReference _collectData = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('messdiary');
// Use the DocumentReference for 'days'.
final DocumentReference _daysData =
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('messdiary').doc('days');
```

Then:-

```
// Change the following statement.
// List<DocumentSnapshot> snaps = snapshot.data!.docs;
// to this:
final daysObj = snapshot.data()!;
final sundayMeals = daysObj["sunday"]
  .map((e)=>todaysMeal(itemName: e['title'], itemImage: e['image'], time: e['time'], dayTime: e['daytime']))
  .toList();
final mondayMeals = ...
...
final saturdayMeals = ...
final mealsData = [...sundayMeals, ...mondayMeals, ....... , ...saturdayMeals];
// Now use mealsData for your carousel.
```

This code might not work entirely as you expected. You have to do any further debugging.

And if you need further help, I might have to charge you .

Comment: thanks for the answer. But how do I  access the values inside those keys?

Comment: You can get a Stream of these arrays: sunday, Monday,...
These arrays will have the individual map objects.

Comment: PLEASE show me how to access that with my code...

Answer (score 0):

```
class messDiary extends StatefulWidget {   messDiary({Key? key}) : super(key: key) {}

  // late String whatIsToday = DateFormat('EEEE').format(DateTime.now());

  @override   State<messDiary> createState() => _messDiaryState(); }

class _messDiaryState extends State<messDiary> {   int activeIndex = 0;   final carouselController = CarouselController();   String valueChoose = 'Select a day';   var itemName;

  final DocumentReference _collectData =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('messdiary').doc('days');

  late Stream<DocumentSnapshot> _streamCollect;

  @override   void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _streamCollect = _collectData.snapshots();   }

  @override   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF000000),
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF000000),
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: const bottomNavigation(),
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          Column(
            children: [
              headings(headingText: "Today's meals"),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 15,
              ),
              StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
                  stream: _streamCollect,
                  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
                    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                      return const Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      );
                    }
                    final snaps = snapshot.data!;
                    final sundayMeals = snaps["sunday"]
                        .map((e) => todaysMeal(
                            itemName: e['title'],
                            itemImage: e['image'],
                            time: e['time'],
                            dayTime: e['daytime']))
                        .toList();
                    final List<Widget> mealsData = [...sundayMeals];
                    return CarouselSlider(
                      options: CarouselOptions(
                        height: height * 0.38,
                        aspectRatio: 2.0,
                        autoPlayCurve: Curves.easeInOutQuart,
                        pauseAutoPlayTouch: true,
                        enlargeCenterPage: true,
                        enableInfiniteScroll: false,
                        initialPage: 2,
                        autoPlay: true,
                        onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
                          setState(() {
                            activeIndex = index;
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                      items: mealsData,
                    );
                  }),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 15,
              ),
              AnimatedSmoothIndicator(
                onDotClicked: animateToSlide,
                effect: const ExpandingDotsEffect(
                    dotWidth: 14,
                    dotHeight: 14,
                    activeDotColor: Color(0xFF6A7086),
                    dotColor: Color(0xFF2B2E3F)),
                activeIndex: activeIndex,
                count: 4,
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 15,
              ),
              const Divider(
                color: Color(0xFF6A6C70),
                indent: 20,
                endIndent: 20,
              ),
          
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );   }

  void animateToSlide(int index) => carouselController.animateToPage(index); }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).